# Object of type 'long' has no len()

Tags: python

[image]

The error appears in the line 10. I don't know how to resolve it.
I want to iterate through a string until finding the character "["

Comment: The error message is clear, `valor` is of type `long` . Simply check if `valor` is string, before going into that loop?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with what you think `valor` is going to be

Comment: Always include your code as text so that a potential answerer can copy and run it.

Answer (score 2):

If you cast the `valor` variable to a string first, you should be able to do those loops on it. However, if the original value was a `long`, I am very doubtful you'll ever find a `[` character in it.

```
valor = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=columnNum).value
```

There is probably some serious problem with this code, but there isn't enough code here to fully diagnose the problem.

Comment: I put the full code. It's about an excell file. I want to delete the content between two brackets: "[ ]"

Answer (score 0):

I edited my post from prior.  This is probably the most direct way, which is using isinstance().

```
if isinstance("apple", str):
    print "apple is a str"
if isinstance(40, str):
    print "40 is a str"
else:
    print "40 is not str"
```

output will be:

apple is a str

40 is not str

Comment: How? I don't know how to do it :(